# Firefox displaying lists wrong

Tags: html, css, list, html-lists

FireFox seems to put any words in list items with more than one word on separate lines, like this:
http://a.flatsi.es/projects/7temwk/images/j7tjrt
But in everything else it is how I want it, like this.
http://a.flatsi.es/projects/7temwk/images/9766kh

A point in the right direction would be super.

HTML

```
<div class="singlenav">
<ul>
<li><a href="/v2">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="/v2/?p=17">About</a></li>
<li><a href="/v2/?p=14">Information</a></li>
<li><a href="/v2/?p=11">Study Skills</a></li>
<li><a href="/v2/?p=8">Discuss</a></li>
<li><a href="/v2/?p=5">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.quicklinks{
width: 100%;
font: bold 20px 'Helvetica',sans-serif;
color: #333;
text-align: left;
margin: 70px 0 0 0;
display:inline-block;
}

.quicklinks li{
white-space: nowrap; 
}


.quicklinks li a{
color: #333;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 10px;
margin: -10px;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML you're using this and any other CSS that would apply to the list? I'm not seeing this based on what you've posted. On a related note, you can use `&nbsp;` between the words or the CSS white-space rule to prevent breaking.

Comment: Thanks @j08691 that adding &nbsp; worked for me, now wondering if there is anything I am doing wrong in css. Thanks again!

Comment: I've just tested my answer against your newly added test case and it works fine on my Fx. The problem is you're depending on default behaviour. If you don't want to be at the mercy of browser defaults you need to be explicit, as in my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Rushyo I have got the white-space rule working now, was just my error before. Thanks for the help!

Comment: In case you're not familiar with the Stack Overflow format: Could you accept the answer by clicking the tick next to it if it helped? Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we don't have a HTML test to go off I'm going to try drawing upon 'psychic powers'. Try this:

```
li { white-space: nowrap; }
```

**Edit**: Works against test case on Fx 15

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try adding a height setting that will manually force it to no go over a certain height.

eg:

height: 100px;

Answer (score 0):

I think the negative margin in `li a` means that inside of `a` wants to be bigger than its box and therefore wraps the word if wrappable. I've never seen a negative margin equal on parallel sides, but if that actually shrinks an element I'm probably wrong.